# Issue with RGBA32F texture format and mipmapping using OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: opengl-es, textures, mipmaps, opengl-es-3.0

When I use `glGenerateMipmap()` to generate mipmap for a `RGBA32F` texture, it always comes to an `INVALID_OPERATION` error. Binding texture or setting many kinds of texture parameters didn't work.

From OpenGL ES 3.0 specification, I find that `RGBA32F` is not filterable. So is this the reason for the error?

Unfortunately, I can't find any "supported texture formats" tips in the api docs of function `glGenerateMipmap`. If so, then why is `RGBA16F` works well but 32bit float does not?

thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenGL ES 3.0 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf), Section 3.8.10.5:

> If the levelbase array was not specified with an unsized internal format from table 3.3 or a sized internal format that is both color-renderable and **texture-filterable** according to table 3.13, an INVALID_OPERATION error is generated.
>   *(emphasis added)*

You already stated that `RGBA32F` is not texture-filterable while `RGBA16F` is, which is the reason why it is working in the latter case but not in the first.

Also [the docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) mention that explicitly in the error list:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the levelbaselevelbase array was not specified with an unsized internal format or a sized internal format that is both color-renderable and texture-filterable.

Comment: oh, thanks! I read that, but I didn't fully understand it. I have a confusion. According to the statement, `RGBA16F` (not color-renderable, but filterable) should also get an error, but actually it works?

Comment: Some GPUs support more than the spec requires via extensions, or support newer OpenGL ES versions. OpenGL ES 3.2 requires RGBA16F to be renderable and filterable, and will be enabled automatically for a 3.x context if the driver supports it. I'd guess your context actually supports all or some of OpenGL ES 3.2 (most of the newer GPUs on the market do).

Comment: @solidpixel you should be right. The final result differs on specific hardwares.